# python pickleのファイルモード (バイナリモードの必然性)

Tags: python

python のpickleでファイルを保存する場合、バイナリモードで保存することは必須なのでしょうか? 例えば、

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random(100,100,100)

# binary mode
pickle.dump(x, open('hoge.pkl', 'wb'))
# not binary mode
pickle.dump(x, open('fuga.pkl', 'w'))
```

とすると、、'wb' オプションでも、'w'オプションでも、全く同じ出力ファイルが得られるようです。(diffをとると全く差がない)

質問: この 'b' (binary option) を付けないとまずいような状況は何かあるのでしょうか?
'b'をつけるか付けないかで、保存されるものは変わりうるのでしょうか?

ちなみに、私は Linux (Ubuntu) を使っています。

Answer (score 4):

Python3 では`bytes`という型が出来て、`str`と区別されるようになりました。
テキストモードで開かれたファイルオブジェクトの`write`は`str`を要求するので、質問のコードは失敗します。

```
>>> pickle.dump(x, open('fuga.pkl', 'w'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-27-c8e3989f5c8e>", line 1, in <module>
    pickle.dump(x, open('fuga.pkl', 'w'))
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Python2 ではエラーにはなりませんが、テキストモードではデータに改行文字があると、OS標準の改行コードに変更されるので、内容が変わる事がある筈です。pickleが作るデータに改行文字が含まれていて、それの変更がデータのロード時に影響するかどうかは私は分かりません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Python3では、pickleファイルのopenに'b'が必須なんですね。

Answer (score 4):

以降、Python 2.7.10 を前提に話をします。

Python の `open()` 関数ですが、実体は `fileobject.c` の `file_init()` 関数です。

**python2.7.10/Objects/fileobject.c:file_init()**

```
file_init(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
                  :
  if (open_the_file(foself, name, mode) == NULL)
```

**python2.7.10/Objects/fileobject.c:open_the_file()**

```
open_the_file(PyFileObject *f, char *name, char *mode)
          :
#ifdef MS_WINDOWS
          :
  f->f_fp = _wfopen(PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(f->f_name),
                    PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(wmode));
          :
#endif
if (NULL == f->f_fp && NULL != name) {
          :
  f->f_fp = fopen(name, newmode);
```

Windows では `_wfopen()`、その他(Linux, OSX, FreeBSD, etc.)は `fopen()` を使用しています。Linux の man で `fopen(3)` を参照すると、

> **fopen(3)**
>
> The mode string can also include the letter 'b' either as a last character or as a character between the characters in any of the two-character strings described above. This is strictly for compatibility with C89 and **has no effect**; **the 'b' is ignored on all POSIX conforming systems, including Linux**. (**Other systems may treat text files and binary files differently, and adding the 'b' may be a good idea if you do I/O to a binary file** and expect that your program may be ported to non-UNIX environments.)

POSIX 準拠の OS の場合、`fopen()` のモード指定に `b` オプションを付けても付けなくても同じ事になります。

一方、Windows ではどうでしょうか。

[MSDN: fopen、_wfopen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/yeby3zcb(v=vs.100).aspx)

> b
>
> Open in binary (untranslated) mode; translations involving **carriage-return and linefeed characters are suppressed**.

また、`pickle.dump()` 関数を見てみますと、最終的に `cPickcle.c:write_file()` 関数でファイルに出力しているのですが、

**python2.7-2.7.10/Modules/cPickle.c:write_file() function**

```
write_file(Picklerobject *self, const char *s, Py_ssize_t  n)
{
  size_t nbyteswritten;
        :
  nbyteswritten = fwrite(s, sizeof(char), n, self->fp);
        :
```

Windows 上でファイルをテキストモードでオープンした場合、`fwrite()` で `'\n' -> '\r\n'` 変換が発生することになります。

[MSDN: fwrite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/h9t88zwz.aspx)

> The fwrite function writes up to count items, of size length each, from buffer to the output stream. The file pointer associated with stream (if there is one) is incremented by the number of bytes actually written. **If stream is opened in text mode, each linefeed is replaced with a carriage-return – linefeed pair**.

Python が Windows を含むマルチプラットフォーム対応である事を鑑みれば、`pickle.dump()` に渡すファイル(ポインタ)はバイナリモードでオープンしておいた方が良いかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。マルチプラットフォームに配慮すれば、'b'オプションは必須ということですね。